# A more succinct way of saying "everyone you have on your Facebook friend list"?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, idiom-request

I can't really think of a succinct way of saying this. I don't know if it's because of my small vocabulary, but I really can't think of a succinct way of saying this that would roll of the tongue.

For example:

> I sent a "Happy Thanksgiving" message to everyone I had on my Facebook
>   friend list.

Comment: I sent an x to all my FB friends. You don't need: list or have.

Comment: You can drop the 'all' as well.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, unless you want to make clear that you didn't just send it to some of your Facebook friends.

Comment: I'm selling my cars doesn't mean I'm selling some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... to my Facebook friends.

And if "Facebook" is clear from the context you could just say "...to my friends"

If you are worried about using the word "friend" for people that you don't know well, you could say "... to my Facebook contacts".  This isn't the terminology used by Facebook, but it is used in, for example, google mail, and is also clear.

Also you are about 4 months late for Thanksgiving (or 8 months early)!

Comment: Unless he's in Canada, in which case he's closer to 6 months late or early.